# dynamic DNS wildcard

Tags: google-app-engine, mod-rewrite, redirect, domain-name-system, g-suite

You can set the DNS record like mod_rewrite in Apache? Where?

```
anything.myapp.com   >  redirect to   >   myapp.appspot.com/anything
```

dynamically, hundreds of thousands of accounts...

Or do I need the Apache server to redirect?

Thanks.

Comment: not sure what this has to do with google apps or app engine? your question itself is also extremely unclear.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any need to do this, because there's no implicit association between URL and filename in App Engine - you can simply design your app with the URL routing you want in the first place.

If you do absolutely need to do this, you can write some WSGI middleware (in Python), or a servlet filter (in Java) that modifies incoming requests before they're handled.